# Attempting to identify specific values in a dictionary

Tags: c#

I am iterating over one dictionary and putting the values into a list, and then I am trying to compare these values to another dictionary.

```
if (!listOps[sizeList - 1].Operation_KEY.Equals(usedOperationKey.Values))
 {
```

listOps[sizeList-1].Operation_Key is a singular value. Will this line be able to distinguish if listOps is equal to a specific key in the usedOperationKey dictionary?

Comment: Sort of confused as to what you're trying to do here, but for what it's worth have you tried using `listOps[KEYNAMEHERE]` to access the value of your dictionary by hard coded key value?

Comment: "Will this line be able to distinguish if listOps is equal to a specific key in the usedOperationKey dictionary?" no.  you cannot directly compare a single value to a collection.  You could use `Any` or `Contains` but it's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.